# Add comments based on variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

My goal is to search for terms or words in documents against a Master table that contains the terms that should not be used in documents as well as a suggestion for the writer. I have a Master table I call the Matrix that contains two columns: Term, Suggestion.
For example:

Term= ubiquitous Suggestion= "Don't use ubiquitous, instead use everywhere".

I need help to find a way to add Suggestions as comments every time I find a word that is in the Master table.

Below my code. I omitted the loops and user input because the issue is: How to add comments that point to the word that was found in the document being validated.

```
Sub AddSideCommentsToWordDocument()
    Dim MatrixDoc As Word.Document     'This is the master table with terms
    Dim MatrixPath As String           'File path to master table
    Dim DocToValidate As Word.Document 'This is the file in question to validate
    Dim DocumentPath As String         'This is the file path to the file in question
    Dim Suggestion As String           'Variable to store suggested comment
    Dim WordToCheck As String          'Variable to store the word to validate against Master table term
 
    DocumentPath = "C:\Folder\FileInQuestion.docx"    'These paths will come from user input
    MatrixPath = "C:\Folder\Master Terms Matrix.docx" 
    
    Set MatrixDoc = Documents.Open(MatrixPath)     'Open Master Table
    Set DocToValidate = Documents.Open(DocumentPath) 'Open doc in question

   'Get first term from Master Table into a variable
   TermFromMatrix = MatrixDoc.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(ColumnWithTerm).range.Text

   'Get first suggested comment from Master Table into a variable
    Suggestion = MatrixDoc.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(ColumnWithSuggestion).range.Text
 
  'Get first word from document to validate into a variable
    WordToCheck = DocToValidate.Words(i).Text

'Compare first term from Master Table vs. First word from document to validate
    If TermFromMatrix = WordToCheck Then   
        DocToValidate.Comments.Add Text:=Suggestion 'I get the following error: Argument not optional
    End If
    Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `Range` argument which tells Word where to attach the comment:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = 1 To .Range.Words.Count
            If .Words(i).Text = "theme" Then
                .Comments.Add Range:=.Words(i), Text:="not theme"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```